# Responsive outline? - Visual composer

Tags: css

I'm trying to create an outline like in the attached image: [image: examplepage]
So far so good, the outline works and the outline-offset too.

But: in it's current state it is not responsive in any way.

Is there any way I can set the outline-offset to percentages?

Current solution:

```
outline: 5px solid #ccc;
outline-offset: -50px;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `vh` and `vw` units (read more [here](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)) for `outline-offset`.
So your solution would become

```
outline: 5px solid #ccc;
outline-offset -5vw;
```

The solution isn't ideal, but you could tweak the values in certain ranges of viewport widths.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I know this solution is far from ideal but for now you really saved my day. Until I've learned another/better fix this will work fine. Thanks!